This MPI_Gatherv code not working and I don't know why
I wrote this code in C that multiplies a matrix by a vector, locally in each process(ylocal) and then the root process gathers the results in its local vector(y). I am using MPI_Gatherv because it has to be for general size matrices.
My problem is MPI_Gatherv is not copying the ylocal vectors from the non-root processes and I am unable to detect what i am doing wrong.
I am running the code using mpirun -np 3 ./mxvnm 10 10 (I am usinga small matrix 10 by 10 for debugging purposes)
Thank you.
 /* Matrix-vector product. Matrix of N*M */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, N, M;
    float **A, *Avector, *x, *y, temp;
    int numprocs, myid, length, provided, iam, nt, np, r, local_rows, limit, *counts, *displacements;
    float *ylocal;
    char name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    double startMPI, endMPI;

    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &length);

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usar: %s filas columnas\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    N = atoi(argv[1]);  //Rows of the matrix and elements of vector y
    M = atoi(argv[2]);  //Columns of the matrix and elements of vector x
    
    if (myid == 0){
        printf("NPROCS=%d. Matrix dimensions: rows=%d, columns=%d\n",numprocs,N,M);
    }

    printf("Node %s: I am process %d of %d\n",name, myid, numprocs);
    fflush(stdout);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      /* Allocate memory for global matrix */
   if((Avector = (float *) malloc(N*M*sizeof(float))) == NULL)
        printf("Error en malloc Avector[%d]\n",N*M);

      /* Pointer array for addressing A as a matrix */
   if((A = (float **) malloc(N*sizeof(float *))) == NULL)
        printf("Error en malloc del array de %d punteros\n",N);
      /* Asign to access A as a matrix: each pointer pointers to the start of the row */
      /* This way, all rows are consecutively in memory */
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    *(A+i) = Avector+i*M;

      /* Matrix inicialization */
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(j=0; j<M; j++)
        A[i][j] = (0.15*i - 0.1*j)/N;
   

      /* Allocate memory for x vector */
    if((x = (float *) malloc(M*sizeof(float))) == NULL)
        printf("Error en malloc x[%d]\n",M);

      /* x vector inicialization */
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    x[i] = (M/2.0 - i);

    // Assign the parameters related to MPI, rows per procs (np), the remainder if N/P is not exact
    np = N/numprocs;
    r = N%numprocs;

    // Fix the values and variables for root proc
    if(myid == 0){
        if((y = (float *) malloc(N*sizeof(float))) == NULL)
        printf("Error en malloc y[%d]\n",N);

        counts = (int *) malloc(numprocs*sizeof(int));
        displacements = (int *) malloc(numprocs*sizeof(int));

        // Fix the counts buffer 
        for(i=0; i<numprocs; i++){
            if (i < numprocs-1){
                counts[i] = np;
            } else {
                counts[i] = np+r;
            }
        }

        // Fix the displacement bufer
        displacements[0]=0;
        for(i=1; i<numprocs; i++){
            displacements[i] = displacements[i-1] + counts[i-1];
        }
    }

    // Fix the number of rows to be sent and process by each proc and the limit of the local loop
    if (myid == numprocs-1){
        local_rows = np +r;
        limit = ((myid+1)*np) +r;
    } else {
        local_rows = np;
        limit = (myid + 1)*np;
    }

    // Allocate in each process a local vector result of size the number of rows processed
    if((ylocal = (float *) malloc(local_rows*sizeof(float))) == NULL)
        printf("PROC[%d]: Error en malloc ylocal[%d]\n",myid, local_rows);

    if(myid == numprocs-1)
        printf("PROC[%d]: Proceso 2 de 3\n",myid);

    /* Matrix-vector product, y = Ax */    

    startMPI = MPI_Wtime();
    for(i=myid*np; i<limit; i++){
    temp = 0.0;
        for(j=0; j<M; j++){
            temp += A[i][j]*x[j];     
        }        
    ylocal[i] = temp;
    printf("PROC[%d]: despues ylocal[%d]=%g\n",myid, i, ylocal[i]);
    }

    if(myid==0){
        for(i=0; i< numprocs;i++){
        printf("PROC[%d]: counts[%d]=%d, displacements[%d]=%d\n",myid, i, counts[i], i, displacements[i]);
        }
    }

    if(myid == 0)
        printf("PROC[%d]: vector antes y[0]=%g\n",myid, y[0]);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // Gather the ylocal vectors into the global y
    MPI_Gatherv(ylocal, local_rows, MPI_FLOAT, y, counts, displacements, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    endMPI = MPI_Wtime();

    if(myid==0)
        printf("PROC[%d]: vector despues y[0]=%g\n",myid, y[0]);
    if (myid == 0){
        printf("Time (in seconds) = %f \n", endMPI - startMPI);
        printf("Done,  y[0] = %g  y[%d] = %g \n", y[0], N-1, y[N-1]);
        for(i=0; i<N;i++)
            printf("DONE: y[%d]=%g\n",i,y[i]);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}





I tried different ways of assigning the displacements and counts vectors but nothing is working.

when asking a question, please trim your code down to a [mcve] and include your mpirun command line. you do not populate ylocal correctly and valgrind should report it.

@GillesGouaillardet Sorry, first time posting a question and i thought it would be useful if the code had all the info to run it. I am running my program using mpirun -np 3 ./mxvnm 10 10 . I'll edit hte question.
When I print the values of each ylocal and compare them to the serial version they all coincide, so what did you notice to know the ylocal values are not populating well? Also process 2 (in this case, but it happens with the last process no matter how many of them are) is aborting with signal 6.

" i thought it would be useful if the code had all the info to run it. "  -- that's correct and you should trim away any code that isn't needed to reproduce the error. LPT: we often find the original problem in the process of creating the minimal reproduce-able example.

what is the content of ylocal on rank 1 if you simply mpirun -np 2 ./mxvnm 2 1 ?

The content is 0.0375

@GillesGouaillardet I've solved it. As you said I was populating ylocal wrong. Because I was indexing ylocal with variable i from the loop, therefore i was not starting at ylocal[0] in the non-root processes. Thank you for pointing out that ylocal was not being populating correctly as I was focused on MPI_Gatherv.
